# Media controls Bar disappears after appearing for a second in VideoView Android

Tags: android

I am able to play a video using VideoView in combination with MediaController. The problem when I started my activity , a bar appears below with media controllers play,pause,rewind ,progress bar representing video. But it disappears after displaying 1 second. Then I how can  I make this media Controller bar with controls to display as long as my video plays so that I can pause,rewind my video.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `show(0)` on the `MediaController`.

Comment: No, but still it is appearing and going in a second. How to make it show constantly. Are there any listeners for MediaController in Android ? Plz give me suggestions in handling this issue.

Comment: @Android_programmer_camera: Then I suspect you will need to write your own controller.

Comment: hey, some times when trying to play video I am getting only audio rather than video . What will be the reason for this.

Comment: @Android_programmer_camera: If you are using the emulator, that is standard behavior. Video does not play back well in the emulator except with a very fast development machine.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that MediaController class has default timeout of 3000ms or 3seconds. And its show() method replaces our given parameter to its default parameter. Its a stupid bug resulting from untested code at Google.

We need to implement a lousy workaround of replacing the default value by desired value.

Try this:

```
mediaControls = new MediaController(getActivity()){
            @Override
            public void show (int timeout){
                if(timeout == 3000) timeout = 20000; //Set to desired number
                super.show(timeout);
            }
        };
mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaControls);
```